# AngularUI - Accordion trigger a method inside the template using ng-click

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using the AngularUI bootstrap library with templates. I'm wainting to call a custom method inside the template and I was wondering what I need to do in order to get this working? I guess what I'm wanting is to replace the ng-click="isOpen = !isOpen" with my own custom method if possible.

Thanks in advance.

```
       <div class="panel panel-default">\n  <div class="panel-heading">\n    
       <h4 class="panel-  title">\n      
       <a class="accordion-toggle" ng-click="isOpen = !isOpen" accordion- transclude="heading">{{heading}}</a>\n    </h4>\n  
       </div>\n  
       <div class="panel-collapse" collapse="!isOpen">\n      <div class="panel-body" ng-transclude></div>\n  
       </div>\n</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since clicking on the toggle changes the value of `isOpen`,
you can watch it and apply your logic without changing the `ng-click` attribute

```
$scope.$watch('isOpen', function(value) {
  if (value) {
    // your code
  }
});
```

Comment: I ended up overriding the template that comes with bootstrap. I gave the template it's own ng-click event and it worked like a treat. Make sure that if you do override the template that you include it after the bootstrap ui file in your application.